# How to install site-specific modules in a Drupal 7 multi-site?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-multi-domain

I have a "[multi-site](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/multisite/multi-site-sharing-the-same-code-base#site-specific-modules-themes)" installation of Drupal 7, which means that I have these folders in my "sites" folder:

```
all
domain.one
domain.two
domain.x
```

And in each of these folders, I also have "modules" and "themes" folders.

If I click the "install new module" link on the modules page ("admin/modules") from any domain X, Drupal tries to download modules in the "all/modules" folder instead of the "X/modules" folder.

Maybe I am not using the proper phrase to search in Google, but I do not see similar problems, so it may just be my problem.

**How to install site-specific modules in a Drupal 7 multi-site?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the example detailed out in this post: http://www.pixelclever.com/how-set-up-drush-for-multisite-installation which basically requires you to create a `drushrc.php` file for each multisite, which includes the path to the respective modules folder.

Here are the lines from that post that explain

> To start, go to your drush folder where you will find a file entitled example.drushrc.php. Copy that file into the individual site folder in your Drupal multisite installation (sites/yourmultisite), and rename the file to drushrc.php.
>
> Now open that file and add the following line:
>   $command_specific['dl']['destination'] = 'sites/yourmultisite/modules';
>
> or
>
> $command_specific['dl']['destination'] = 'sites/yourmultisite/modules/contributions';

This is also a step by step walkthrough of the updating process using drush on multisites.

http://rinen.net/2013/02/updating-a-drupal-multisite-using-drush/

Comment: Thank you for your time and post, I looked for this information. May be you also know, how can I do this without Drush? May be some variable in settings.php? Drush is good, but inDrupal possibility is also useful for me.

Answer (score 0):

I found good article for multisite install here,

http://mydons.com/drupal-7-multisite-install-steps-in-linux/

http://mydons.com/drupal-7-multisite-install-steps-in-windows/

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

1. Changed working directory on terminal to specific site directory 
   i.e. **"cd [drupal_site_directory]/sites/[site_one]/ "**
2. use usual drush command to install modules i.e. **"drush dl [module_name]"**

Hope this might help you guys also.

.